# "ERROR 403: Forbidden" when trying to download CuDNN on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, cudnn

I am trying to install CuDNN on virtual machine but when I tried to download it using the following command:

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/7.6.5.32/Production/
10.0_20191031/cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.tgz
```

I will get this error even when I tried as root:

```
--2020-07-10 13:03:21--  https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/7.6.5.32/Production/10.0_20191 031/cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.tgz Resolving developer.nvidia.com (developer.nvidia.com)... 152.199.16.29 Connecting to developer.nvidia.com (developer.nvidia.com)|152.199.16.29|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2020-07-10 13:03:21 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: I had the same issue. I'm wondering how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbiddens are because you do not have permission to view or access the file or resource. It could be that your permissions are not correct. Have you signed up for the NVIDIA Developer Program?

Additionally, Make sure you have cuDNN Library for Linux for CUDA and run the `scp` command

Edit: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73) is a guide for installing CuDNN on Ubuntu

Comment: that is what I did. got the link from here:

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: added a guide to my answer